# since I upgraded to 17.10 my usb wifi ANEWKODI (Realtek) doesn't work anymore

Tags: drivers, kernel, compiling, realtek-wireless

I tried this:

http://xhyumiracle.com/how-to-install-rtl8812au-driver-on-ubuntu-for-wireless-usb-adapters/
and get this:

```
geoffrey@geoffrey-H110M-S2H:~/rtl8812AU$ make CC=/usr/bin/gcc-5
make ARCH=x86_64 CROSS_COMPILE= -C /lib/modules/4.13.0-16-generic/build M=/home/geoffrey/rtl8812AU  modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.13.0-16-generic'
  CC [M]  /home/geoffrey/rtl8812AU/core/rtw_cmd.o
In file included from /home/geoffrey/rtl8812AU/include/drv_types.h:32:0,
                 from /home/geoffrey/rtl8812AU/core/rtw_cmd.c:22:
/home/geoffrey/rtl8812AU/include/osdep_service.h: In function ‘thread_enter’:
/home/geoffrey/rtl8812AU/include/osdep_service.h:343:2: error: implicit declaration of function ‘allow_signal’ [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
  allow_signal(SIGTERM);
  ^
/home/geoffrey/rtl8812AU/include/osdep_service.h: In function ‘flush_signals_thread’:
/home/geoffrey/rtl8812AU/include/osdep_service.h:353:6: error: implicit declaration of function ‘signal_pending’ [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
  if (signal_pending (current)) 
      ^
/home/geoffrey/rtl8812AU/include/osdep_service.h:355:3: error: implicit declaration of function ‘flush_signals’ [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
   flush_signals(current);
   ^
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
scripts/Makefile.build:302: recipe for target '/home/geoffrey/rtl8812AU/core/rtw_cmd.o' failed
make[2]: *** [/home/geoffrey/rtl8812AU/core/rtw_cmd.o] Error 1
Makefile:1546: recipe for target '_module_/home/geoffrey/rtl8812AU' failed
make[1]: *** [_module_/home/geoffrey/rtl8812AU] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.13.0-16-generic'
Makefile:1576: recipe for target 'modules' failed
make: *** [modules] Error 2
geoffrey@geoffrey-H110M-S2H:~/rtl8812AU$ sudo make install
install -p -m 644 8812au.ko  /lib/modules/4.13.0-16-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/
install: cannot stat '8812au.ko': No such file or directory
Makefile:1582: recipe for target 'install' failed
make: *** [install] Error 1
```

This worked correctly on 17.04

any ideas?

Comment: thanks for the formating edwinksl, how do I do that for the next time?

Comment: It is enough to switch to new driver version which is compatible with new kernel. https://github.com/aircrack-ng/rtl8812au/tree/v4.3.21

Answer (score 0):

I spent all morning searching through the net and have managed to fix my problem. I'm not sure exactly what fixed it yet as i tried a lot of things.
What I didn't do was reboot after each modification.
I'll try to sift through to find the explanation, but at least I can say that the ANEWKODI (Realtek) USB Wifi key works with Ubuntu 17.10

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue: I have an [Anekwodi 600Mbps Dual Band Wifi Adapter](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01G8IPLD8) and it did not have a driver in Ubuntu 18.10. To enable the adapter, I used the following commands to install the driver (as described [here](https://robtranquillo.wordpress.com/2017/08/27/linux-driver-for-anewkodi-usb-wifi-dongle/) and [here](https://github.com/gnab/rtl8812au)):

```
wget https://github.com/gnab/rtl8812au/archive/master.zip
unzip master.zip
cd rtl8812au-master/
make
sudo insmod  8812au.ko
```

Note: This required installing the package `libelf-dev` with the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install libelf-dev
```