# RTL8812AU Failing While Attempting Hotspot Setup

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, network-manager, ethernet

Fresh install of 19.04, running alongside an installation of Windows 10 (different drives). I have an ethernet cable coming into my [onboard port](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/82186/intel-ethernet-connection-i219-v.html), which I use for my main connection. I also have the [ANEWKODI](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01G8IPLD8) wireless adapter plugged in. This device does not natively support Linux, so the drivers I am using are installed following [this guide](https://askubuntu.com/questions/966665/since-i-upgraded-to-17-10-my-usb-wifi-anewkodi-realtek-doesnt-work-anymore).

After installing a new driver, `iw list` lists my device, but I am no longer able to view available networks

[image]

My goal is to - using the ethernet as a source, create a hotspot using the wifi dongle.

Running `lshw -c network` yields [this](https://pastebin.com/XKa5xGMG).

`iw list` returns [this](https://pastebin.com/Jx5REup9)

Trying to start the `hostapd` service also shoots an error:

```
Sep 20 19:40:56 david systemd[1]: Failed to start Advanced IEEE 802.11 AP and IE
-- Subject: A start job for unit hostapd.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
```

**What I've tried so far:**

I've followed the steps listed [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1155827/431864), which recommended manually starting the `network-manager` process, [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1098979/431864), which said to disable fast boot from Windows, and [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1065331/431864), which was a reinstall of `network-manager`, none of which worked.

Comment: What's the output of `iw list`?  Windows 10 working is not a methodology of assuming your hardware supports being a hotspot, unfortunately.

Comment: @fabby updated again, after installing a new driver, iw list now seems to list my device

Comment: And it supports Access Point Mode `Supported interface modes:
* AP` however, I cannot seem to find the vendor for this hardware. What is the vendor and model number?

Comment: @fabby The second link in the question is a link to the Amazon page where I originally bought it, but you're right. I've had a great deal of difficulty finding more information about the dongle